Python opening shared object fails on Android
I have created a shared object and have attempted to call it from QPython 3.6.6 on android using ctypes, and get the following dlopen fail error.
A similar error (library is not accessible for the namespace "(default)" ) also occurs using Pydroid 3.
The python code works correctly on Windows with a dll.
/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython3-android5.sh  /storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/.last_tmp.py  && exit
thon/scripts3/.last_tmp.py  && exit            <
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/.last_tmp.py", line 6, in <module>
    current_working_directory+"/scripts3/libsquare_dll.so")
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/ctypes/__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
  File "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python36.zip/ctypes/__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
OSError: dlopen failed: library "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/libsquare_dll.so" needed or dlopened by "/data/user/0/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-36m.so" is not accessible for the namespace "(default)"

C code of the shared object is:
#include <stdint.h>
#include "pch.h"

extern "C" {
    void mysquare(uint64_t  n, uint64_t* result) {
        *result = n * n;
    }
}

Python code is:
import ctypes
from os import getcwd

current_working_directory = getcwd()
squaredll = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary (
    current_working_directory+"/scripts3/libsquare_dll.so")

square_dll = squaredll.mysquare

res = ctypes.c_ulonglong()

for n in range(10):
  square_dll(n, ctypes.byref(res) )
  s = res.value
  print(n, s )
  


You should have tried in on Linux. Not the cause of your problem, but check  [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions). Anyway, based on the error message this looks (to me) more like an Android permission issue.

Thanks for the input, but I'm not sure what would be gained by trying on Linux.  Do you know what can be done to remove the Android permission issue?
It doesn't seem to be related to ctypes returning an incorrect value as it doesn't get that far.
